# Find the general solution of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to find the general solution to this system of equations using an augmented matrix, and then using the gauss elimination, but I cant seem to get it into row echelon form no matter what i try. The system is:
$$x-2y-z+3w=0$$
$$-2x+4y+5z-5w=3$$
$$3x-6y-6z+8w=-3$$
If someone could please give me some pointers on where to go, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you in advance. Matt

Comment: you might want to include what you have currently and we can see how you are stuck?

Comment: @MattSpahr: $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -2 & 0 & \dfrac{10}{3} & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{3} & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that you have not yet noticed, that if you add the first two equations you get the third one.

Comment: Maybe you meant subtract the second from the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

First take notice that you have a 3 by 4 coefficients matrix, meaning that you have more variables than equations, therefore there is a general solution or no solution.

We have

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & -2 & -1 & 3&  0 \\ 
-2 & 4 & 5 & -5 &3 \\ 
3 & -6 & -6 & 8 & -3 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$$

We will do the following elementary row operations $2R_1+R_2\to R_2$ and  $-3R_1+R_3\to R_3$ to get

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & -2 & -1 & 3&  0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 1 &3 \\ 
0 & 0 & -3 & -1 & -3 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$$

Next $R_2+R_3\to R_3$ and we got

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & -2 & -1 & 3&  0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 1 &3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$$

Which has written in the comments, the third row is a linear combination of the first and second rows

And we got the [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)

going back to the system of linear eqautions

\begin{array}{lcl} x  -2y  -z +3w = 0 \\ 3z+w = 3 \end{array}

Let set $w=t$ and from the second equation we get

$$3z=3-t\iff z=1-\frac{t}{3}$$

Back substituting to the first equation we get

$$x-2y-(1-\frac{t}{3})+t=0\iff x=2y-\frac{4}{3}t+1$$ setting $y=s$ we get

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2s-\frac{4}{3}t+1 \\
s\\
1-\frac{t}{3}\\
t
\end{pmatrix}=t
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{4}{3} \\
0\\
-\frac{1}{3}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}+s
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 \\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$